# How to make a hidden listview (Android wear)

Tags: wear-os

I'm trying to make a GUI for a wear App which contains a hidden horizontal listwiew that allows the user to perform some actions. the listwiew should get shown when the user swipe dawn.

this is an example of what I would like to have :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUvPd.gif)

could anyone please show me how I can implement it ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [GridViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/2d-picker.html) is what you need. You probably also want to add [DotsPageIndicator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/DotsPageIndicator.html) to your GridViewPager. For example:

```
GridViewPager gridViewPager = (GridViewPager)findViewById("GridViewPagerId");
DotsPageIndicator pageIndicator = (DotsPageIndicator)findViewById("DotsPageIndicator");

YourCustomFragmentGridPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new YourCustomFragmentGridPagerAdapter("Your data");
gridViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
pageIndicator.setPager(gridViewPager);
```